# Why is root taking ownership of my process?

Tags: centos, systemd, process

Recently I noticed that root sometimes takes ownership of my process.

For example:
I started process as me(let's say John). Process is running(as a daemon), and when I do ps -ef I see process is owned by me.

BUT ! My monitoring reported me that my process count is 0(I am checking if process exists, and if owner is me). So I started loop every 10 second to check ps -ef output, and log.

And then I saw something weird....every few minutes(10-100) process ownership changes from me to root, and then gets back to me after few secs(I was checking every 10s). I checked the logs, but it does not say anything about this.

Is this normal ? If not, how to debug this ?

I am running it on CentOS 7.4

Comment: What is your process doing?

Comment: It is cluster execution daemon, it is responsible for comunicating with amster, and running jobs

Comment: Would also be interesting to know if the PID stays the same during the change of ownership.  If not, the process got respawned or forked from a different user.